# What are ways to extract the juice from a pomegranate?

Tags: fruit, juice, pomegranate

Is there an efficient way to extract the juice from a fresh pomegranate?

Answer (score 8):

Luckily you asked for an efficient way and not a clean way!

My brother in California has numerous mature pomegranate trees on his property and squeezes the majority of the fruit each year to use for jelly.  He uses a manual [Hamilton Beach Orange juicer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00015NN0S) which he says does the best job of anything he's tried.  He usually has between 16-20 gallons of juice a year so he has definitely put it to the test.  His local restaurant supply wanted around $250 for one but he got his on ebay for $150.

To minimize the mess he does it on an old table outside and covers himself with a large garbage bag by cutting a hole in the bottom for his head and the sides for his arms.

Comment: In my area of the world, you get street vendors with all sorts of fresh fruit and one of these manual juicers. Pick any fruit you want and they'll juice it into a cup for you, pomegranates included. 
It seems to work quite well, and I don't recall seeing any red-stained vendors.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I've come across is to separate the jewels, wrap them up in cheesecloth, and twist the cheesecloth slowly so that the juice is pressed out into a waiting bowl.